# Using scp to transfer files from unix to windows

Tags: ftp, winscp

I have a windows 7 laptop (not windows server, just a regular laptop). A unix machine is trying to drop a file to this windows machine. If i don't want to setup an FTP server on my windows, can the unix user still drop files using scp?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you are looking for but can accomplish the same goal with relative ease. Using [powercat](https://github.com/besimorhino/powercat) you can set up a listener on the windows box and drop a file from the unix machine.

windows machine (listener):

```
powercat -l -p 8000 -of C:\file.txt
```

unix box (using native nc):

```
nc -nv ip_addr_of_windows_box 8000 < file.txt
```

Additionally, you could also run a server on the unix box and pull the files from the windows machine over http, though this isn't the safest method as you will be exposing the file system..

unix box:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

windows (powershell):

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://ip_of_unix_box:8000/file.txt -OutFile c:\temp\file.txt
```